# Getting all rows where for column 'C' the entry is larger than the preceding element in column 'C'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

How can I select all rows of a data frame where a condition is met according to a column, which has to do with the relationship between every 2 entries of that column.  To give the specific example, lets say I have a DataFrame:

```
>>>df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [ 1, 2, 3, 4],
                      'B':['spam', 'ham', 'egg', 'foo'],
                      'C':[4, 5, 3, 4]})
>>> df
   A     B  C
0  1  spam  4
1  2   ham  5
2  3   egg  3
3  4   foo  4
>>>df2 = df[ return every row of df where C[i] > C[i-1] ]

>>> df2
   A    B  C
1  2  ham  5
3  4  foo  4
```

There is plenty of great information about slicing and indexing in the pandas docs and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-values-in-a-column-in-pandas), but this is a bit more complicated, I think.  I could also be going about it wrong.  What I'm looking for is the rows of data where the value stored in C is no longer monotonously declining.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with compare by [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html)ed column values:

```
print (df[df['C'] > df['C'].shift()])
   A    B  C
1  2  ham  5
3  4  foo  4
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df['C'] > df['C'].shift())
0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
Name: C, dtype: bool
```

If want all monotonously declining rows compare [`diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.diff.html) of column:

```
print (df[df['C'].diff() > 0])
   A    B  C
1  2  ham  5
3  4  foo  4
```